# Unable to create a zImage from Image

Tags: android, image, compilation, kernel

I am trying to compile cm11 kernel for my xperia zl(odin). I was able to compile the Image ( with a few warnings) but after the Image is ready I get:

```
Kernel: arch/arm/boot/Image is ready
LZO arch/arm/boot/compressed/piggy.lzo
AS arch/arm/boot/compressed/piggy.lzo.o
CC arch/arm/boot/compressed/misc.o
CC arch/arm/boot/compressed/decompress.o
CC arch/arm/boot/compressed/string.o
SHIPPED arch/arm/boot/compressed/lib1funcs.S
AS arch/arm/boot/compressed/lib1funcs.o
SHIPPED arch/arm/boot/compressed/ashldi3.S
AS arch/arm/boot/compressed/ashldi3.o
LD arch/arm/boot/compressed/vmlinux

/home/allspark/android/toolchain/android-toolchain-eabi/bin/arm-eabi-ld: error:       arch/arm/boot/compressed/piggy.lzo.o: unknown CPU architecture
/home/allspark/android/toolchain/android-toolchain-eabi/bin/arm-eabi-ld: error: arch/arm/boot/compressed/lib1funcs.o: unknown CPU architecture
/home/allspark/android/toolchain/android-toolchain-eabi/bin/arm-eabi-ld: error: arch/arm/boot/compressed/ashldi3.o: unknown CPU architecture
make[2]: *** [arch/arm/boot/compressed/vmlinux] Error 1
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/boot/compressed/vmlinux] Error 2
make: *** [zImage] Error 2
```

Any help is appreciated

edit:I need a zImage in order to create a boot.img. PS : I am new to Linux OS (I use Linux Mint)

Answer (score 0):

I saw this exact error when trying to build an Android image and it was related to the gcc version used. I had mine pointed at an arm-linux-androideabi-4.8 version, but moving back to version 4.6 fixed this specific error. See if you can find out what version you should be building with and make sure that is setup properly in your $PATH/toolchain.